# Performance for SELECT query to check if the record exist in the table or not

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Let's say I've [User] table and I want to check if the email exist in that table or not. Are there any differences between following two queries? Which one will perform fast and why?

**Option 1**:

```
DECLARE @EXIST as bit

SELECT TOP 1 @EXIST = 1 
FROM [dbo].[User]
WHERE UserEmail = N'email@email.com'
```

**Option 2**:

```
DECLARE @EXIST as bit
SELECT @EXIST = 1 
FROM [dbo].[User]
WHERE UserEmail = N'email@email.com'
```

I think option 1 might be faster because of TOP 1, but not exactly sure since I'm not SQL expert.

Comment: Very easy, just see execution plans

Comment: Add this on your testing:
`IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM FROM [dbo].[User]
WHERE UserEmail = N'email@email.com') SET @EXIST = 1`.

Comment: TOP 1 could require sorting. It would also depend on having indexes on the User/UserEmail columns. Apart from that, there won't be much improvement on there kinds of databases.

Comment: @Pieter21: `TOP 1 1` does not require sorting!     On a column without any index Option1 is 6% and Option2 94%.   On a primary key column (unique clustered index) it's 50:50. Tested on a table with 80K records - result may/will vary with the number of records....

Comment: @CeOnSql Let's say the column doesn't have indexing and table has 20 records. 5th record contains email@email.com. Is it safe to assume, option 1 will only traverse first 5 records and will return the result as soon as the item found, and option 2 will traverse all records?

Comment: if there is not ANY index on the table (no primary key, no nonclustered index), the statements will be 50:50 and SLOW- SQL Server will always have to perform a table scan!

Comment: if you want to achieve best possible performance your table should have a clustered index respectively a primary key and a nonclustered index on UserEmail. The fastest operation would be if  `UserEmail` is the primary key column or covered in uique clustered index.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Exists clause since it is specifically for existence check.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM FROM [dbo].[User] WHERE UserEmail = N'email@email.com') SET @EXIST = 1
```

If you plan to choose only between 2 options then go for option-1 since there might be an error if your table contains duplicate records for the given email when we choose option-2.

We have to check the execution plan before making any decision.